# Generate random number in JavaScript but few numbers should be in less frequent

Tags: javascript, random

I am able to generate Random number from 0 to 10 using below code snippet, but I want frequency of 0 and 1 to be less when compared to any other number.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)
```

That would be great if someone provides me the solution without having external conditions to it.

Comment: What have you tried ? What do you mean by "external conditions" ?

Comment: Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: I do not want to keep condition on the resulted number and fire the random generator if the result is 0 or 1, especially when 0 or 1 had occurred in last 15 occurrences.

Comment: hey, I am saying that, "I do not want to keep such external arrays logic around it". Please let me know if there is any standard solution for it.

Comment: Not everything comes nicely packed for immediate consumption, sometimes we have to make the effort to cook the final product given the ingredients; What u are asking for is too specific to be have a STANDARD SOLUTION; Unless we use an external logic, I dont think there is much that could be done. I could still be wrong . So, feel free to challenge me and come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a probability for `0` and `1` with the half of the rest of the numbers by taking a formular with a factor of `18` and an offset of `2` then take the rest with `10` of it.

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 18 + 2) % 10;
```

The result is like this:

```js
var i,
    count = {},
    index;

for (i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18 + 2) % 10;
    count[index] = (count[index] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```